# MySQLdb windows create database

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to create a `MySQL database` in `python`.

I am using `MySQL db`.

Currently, here is what I do:

```
import MySQLdb    
db1 = MS.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="****")
```

Everywhere I go it seems that everybody assumes that you know how to create a database, but I do not.  As you could guess when I run the above code I get an error, and I assume it is because I have not created a database.

How do I create a database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL on the commandline/terminal:

```
$ echo 'CREATE DATABASE <dbname>;' | mysql -u <username> -p
```

where

- `<dbname>`   : Name for New Database,
- `<username>` :  is your mysql username.

Also you need to type your mysql `<password>` when prompted.

OR:

you can also use: `mysql -u <username> -p -e "create database <dbname>";`

Answer (score 0):

You can create the database this way.

```
import MySQLdb
db1 = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="****")
cursor = db1.cursor()
sql = 'CREATE DATABASE mynewDatabase'
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Then you can create another connection with already a database selected for your queries or do a `USE mynewDatabase` and use that same cursor to execute your queries, making sure it remembers that you already said `USE`.